# getting error "Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: local" when running script localy

Tags: ansible

I get error "[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: local"
when I run the below command

```
ansible-playbook -i getinventory.py playbook.yml
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Manage upstreams dynamically using Ansible
  hosts: local
  # become: yes
  vars:
    upstream_name: my_upstream
    shards: "{{ groups['app_servers'] }}" # or you can use a variable instead
  tasks:
    - name: Render upstream configuration template
      template:
        src: templates/upstream.conf.j2
        dest: templates/{{ upstream_name }}.conf
      notify: reload nginx
```

getinventory.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

ip_list = [
    '10.0.0.1',
    '10.0.0.2',
    '10.0.0.3',
]

inventory = {
    'app_servers': {
        'hosts': ip_list,
    },
}

print(json.dumps(inventory))
```

Comment: You don’t have a `local` group in this inventory indeed; you have a `app_servers` groups. You either meant `hosts: localhost` or `hosts: app_servers` and `connection: local`, I’d guess.